# If f1 and f2 are 2 continous functions then f = { f1(x), x is rational and f2(x) , x is irational is continous in x0 if only if f1(x0)=f2(x0)

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that.

I know that i have to take a string with rational number and a string with irational numbers but i don;t know how to do next.

Please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint (just one side)**

Assume $x_0$ irrational.

Being the rational numbers dense in $\mathbb{R}$ one could take a succesion $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ $x_n \to x_0$
By continuity of $f_1$ and $f$ if we take $\epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$:
$$|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$
$$|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f_1(x)-f_1(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

Take $N \ \forall n>N: |x_n-x_0|<\delta$

Then by continuity:

$$|x_n-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x_n)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$
$$|x_n-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f_1(x_n)-f_1(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

How $x_n$ is rational, and $x_0$ is irrational:

$$|x_n-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f_1(x_n)-f_2(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

So:

$$|f_1(x_0)-f_2(x_0)|\leq |f_1(x_0)-f_1(x_n)+f_1(x_n)-f_2(x_0)|$$
$$\leq |f_1(x_0)-f_1(x_n)|+|f_1(x_n)-f_2(x_0)|\leq2\epsilon$$

Then the difference $|f_1(x_0)-f_2(x_0)|$ is arbitrary small then are equal.

When $x_0$ is rational is analogous using the density of the irrational numbers.

Comment: I understand all less the last part . why f1(x0)=f2(x0) if the module is < 2 epsilon

Comment: If for all $\epsilon$,  $|a-b|<\epsilon$ then $a=b$. Try to prove it

Comment: If you need help tell me

Comment: I understand know . Thank you very much . But i have one more question . I have to prove also that the points where f is differentiable are f1'(x0)=f2'(x0)

Comment: Take a look in this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76142/if-the-condition-of-differentiability-holds-for-the-rationals-then-the-function?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If $f_1(x_0)\neq f_2(x_0)$, take a sequence $(x_n)$ of rational numbers and a sequence $(y_n)$ of irrational numbers such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=x_0$. Obviously $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)\neq\lim_{n\to \infty}f(y_n)$. Now assume $f_1(x_0)= f_2(x_0)$. For a given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta_1,\delta_2$, such that $|x_0-x|<\delta_1\implies |f_1(x_0)-f_2(x)|<\epsilon$ and $|x_0-x|<\delta_2\implies |f_2(x_0)-f_2(x)|<\epsilon$. Put $\delta:=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Then $|x_0-x|<\delta\implies |f(x_0)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.